# Can I select the value of an input without a name or ID?

Tags: javascript, input, inline

[image]

I am creating a dynamic table (as seen above), but I do so by looping through my data object. Currently you fill out the data in the top section, then click stage, and the data is added to the table. I'd like to be able to update the data in the table as well.

This is how the table is built:

```
<?php
for($r = 0; $r < sizeof($dataArray); $r++){
    for($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++){
        Echo "<td>
                  <input onchcange='updateData("WHAT GOES HERE?", ".$r.", ".$i.")' value='".$dataArray[$r][$i]."'>
             </td>";
    }
}
?>
```

`updateData()` should take 3 parameters: the ROW, the COLUMN, and the new VALUE.

**How can I select the new value from the input?**

Comment: `onchcange` should probably be `onchange`

Comment: `"WHAT GOES HERE?"` is `this.value`.

Comment: @kenney If you post your solution as an answer I can give you credit for solving it.

Comment: Im not sure what your data structure looks like. Assumed you had a some kind of sql db on the backend and would need a record Id to update the data structure, but you are using numeric indexes for row and field so my answer is not going to work for that. Thanks for the upvote, but it wasn't deserved.

Comment: @Shanimal you caught my typo and put in a great effort to help. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the input element, or it's value, to the callback:

```
              <input onchange='updateData(this.value, ".$r.", ".$i.")' value='".$dataArray[$r][$i]."'>
```

Generally, `this` in an event handler context points to the element the handler is defined on.